# Not getting proper data using json encoding for a structure in go language

Tags: json, serialization, encoding, tcp, go

```
//package cluster
package main

import (
"encoding/csv"
"encoding/json"
"fmt"
"io"
"math/rand"
"net"
"os"
"strconv"
"time"
//"bytes"
)

const (
BROADCAST = -1
 )

var outbox, inbox chan *Envelope
var pids [10]int
var ips [10]string

type Envelope struct {
Pid   int
MsgId int64
Msg   interface{}
}

type Server interface {
Pid() int
Peers() []int
Outbox() chan *Envelope
Inbox() chan *Envelope
}

/*
func (envelope Envelope) Pid() int {
return envelope.MsgId
}
*/
var server Envelope

func (envelope Envelope) Peers() []int {
return nil //pids
}

func (envelope Envelope) Outbox() chan *Envelope {
return outbox
}

func (envelope Envelope) Inbox() chan *Envelope {
return inbox
}

func server_() {
// listen on a port
ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":9999")
//time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
for {
    c, err := ln.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        continue
    } else {
        fmt.Println("handle")
        go handleServerConnection(c)
    }
} 
}

func handleServerConnection(c net.Conn) {
// receive the message
var msg Envelope
var b []byte
//  for{
c.Read(b)
/*
    if b == nil{
        continue
    }else{
        break
    }
*/
//  }

fmt.Println(b)
err := json.Unmarshal(b, &msg)
if err != nil { //ERORR !!!!
    fmt.Println(err)
} else {
    fmt.Println("Received : %+v", msg)
}
c.Close()
}

func client() {
// connect to the server
for msg := range outbox {
    c, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:9999")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error encoding the response to a join request")
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    b, _ := json.Marshal(msg)
    fmt.Printf("the json: %s\n", b)
    c.Write(b)
    c.Close()
}
time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
}

func New(myPid int, ConFile string) Envelope {
inbox = make(chan *Envelope, 100)
outbox = make(chan *Envelope, 100)
file, err := os.Open(ConFile)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
}
defer file.Close()
reader := csv.NewReader(file)

i := 0
j := 0
for {
    record, err := reader.Read()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    }
    x, _ := strconv.Atoi(record[0])
    pids[i] = x
    i++
    ips[j] = record[1]
    j++
}

fmt.Println("\n", ips)
fmt.Println("\n", pids)
MsgId := rand.Int63n(0x10000000)
server = Envelope{Pid: myPid, MsgId: MsgId, Msg: "Hello World :)"}

go server_()
go client()
var input string
fmt.Println("\n\nPress enter ---\n\n")
fmt.Scanln(&input)
return server
}

func main() {
//for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
server := New(12, "config.txt")

server.Outbox() <- &Envelope{Pid: BROADCAST, MsgId: server.MsgId, Msg: "hello there"}
select {
case envelope := <-server.Inbox():
    fmt.Printf("Received msg from %d: '%s'\n", envelope.Pid, envelope.Msg)

case <-time.After(2 * time.Second):
    println("Waited and waited. Ab thak gaya\n")
}

//fmt.Println(server.Pid, server.MsgId, server.Msg )
//}

}
```

From client function I am trying to send some data but unable to receive data in handleServerConnection()

my program is written in go language 
help me out

I have referred most of the examples given in the book and stack overflow

i am getting an empty object in handleconnection function

Comment: Can you post a short, self-contained example of your question instead?  Preferably one that runs on the playground (play.golang.org).  Where is the JSON you're decoding?  What are you getting?  What do you expect?

Comment: You are catching and printing numerous errors in your code. Do they ever get printed out? If so, can you add them to your question? Make sure to catch any error from c.Read(). My guess is that that call is giving you an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share an example of the json you are trying to decode?  I suspect that it is an annotations issue.  Most json is lowercase due to the javascript syntax.

For instance, I suspect your json looks like this:

```
{"pid":"0", "msgId":"500", "msg":"this is the message"}
```

If that is the case, then you need annotations on your struct like this:

```
type Envelope struct {
    Pid   int         `json:"pid"`
    MsgId int64       `json:"msgId"`
    Msg   interface{} `json:"msg"`
}
```

Again, without an example, I'm only guessing that this is your problem.